# remote debugging with tomcat/eclipse, while others are sharing system

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I have setup tomcat for remote debugging through eclipse, I have added following configuration in tomcat startup script

export JPDA_ADDRESS=9999

export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket

echo $JPDA_ADDRESS

…….

exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"

However, there are multiple developers working on this server and when my debugger stops at breakpoint I added, other developers get stuck, is there anyway in tomcat which will allow other developers to continue running application seamlessly while I am debugging?

Answer (score 1):

As you made me realise, you really need a second independent tomcat instance.  As underlined in the comment below, the debug breakpoint mechanism in the JVM would stop *all* webapps reaching the breakpoint even if you duplicate them (said otherwise regardless of the number of working threads, each thread would freeze and wait or resume signal).

Comment: so basically making copy of entire app dir under /tomcat/webapps to make it look like two difffernt apps?

Comment: Yes, you would freeze only one worker thread of the running instance.  Otherwise, just have another tomcat instance (with a different CATALINA_BASE in which you have your webapp).  There might be better solutions in which you could still have several worker threads for a given webapp but if there are singletons, that wouldn't work.

Comment: sorry but then when tomcat starts up how it's going to know which one to run in debug mode or to connect from eclipse client?

Comment: You're right, my suggestion is rubbish. Setting a breakpoint in eclipse would stop all webapps reaching the breakpoint.  I'll correct my answer right away.